# programs open and computer overheats while in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, overheating

i recently changed my laptop's OS from Windows 10 to ubuntu 17.04 and every time i shut the screen (which would originally on Windows 10 just suspend it) the laptop gets very hot over a short amount of time and when i open the laptop again and type in my password several programs have started at random (sometimes several terminals open up, sometimes filesystem, etc) What is this problem and how to i fix it? Thank you!

Comment: So your computer is obviously not suspending. When you open "System Settings" and click on "Power", make sure the two options next to "When the lid is closed" are set to "Suspend". Probably it is configured to do nothing. Btw, does what you describe happen while the power adapter is plugged in or not?

Comment: i checked the power setting and yes they both were set to suspend.  This occurs whether it i plugged in or not.

Comment: You could check your system logs for error messages around the time  you send your computer to sleep.

Comment: I am pretty sure we already had a question here on AU on the same topic but I cannot find it. Basically Ubuntu is not detecting the lid movement correctly on your computer. So when you close the screen it actually gets a bit crazy like you random pushed some keys. You need to look for how to get suspension to work correctly.

Comment: Also please [edit] your question to specify relevant hardware information so we can vote to reopen it. :)

Comment: I finally fixed! Tried dozens of different tricks that didn't work. At the end it was just to enable "Runtime Power management" and "Extended Idle Power states" in the Bios.
https://pasteboard.co/teVWw8wvkMWp.png
Hope this can help